# Laravel Raw query convert into Eloquent ORM format

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

can anyone help me to convert this query

```sql
SELECT 
   employees.username, 
   employees_attendance.employees_id, 
   SUM(employees_attendance.worked_hours) 
FROM 
   employees_attendance 
LEFT JOIN 
   employees ON 
   employees_attendance.employees_id=employees.id 
WHERE 
   timein LIKE '2020-03-26 %' 
GROUP BY 
   employees_attendance.employees_id
```

into laravel eloquent ORM `2020-03-27` today date.

I wrote like this but syntax voilation error

```php
DB::table('employees_attendance')
          ->leftJoin('employees', 'employees_attendance.employees_id', '=', 'employees.id')
          ->where('employees_attendance.employees_id', '=', 'employees.id')
          ->whereDate('timein', Carbon::today())
          ->select('employees.id as emp_id','employees.username as name')
          ->groupBy('employees_attendance.employees_id')
          ->get();
```

Comment: Show the error you get also.

Comment: @BadPiggie Error is LIke this QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: select `employees_attendance`.`worked_hours`, `employees`.`username`, SUM(employees_attendance.worked_hours) AS minites from `employees_attendance` left join `employees` on `employees`.`id` = `employees_attendance`.`employees_id` where `employees_attendance`.`timein` LIKE 2020-03-27%)